# Processing two lists, iterating line by line and join values

Tags: python, list, loops, matrix

```
w = open("input1.txt", "r")
f = open("input2.txt", "r")
for line1 in w:
    words1 = line1.split()
    for line2 in f:
        words2 = line2.split()
        print (words1[0]+" "+words1[1]+" "+words1[2]+" "+words1[3]+" "+words1[4]+" "+words1[5]+";"+words2[0])

f.close()
w.close()
```

I have one list in each text file: input1.txt and input2.txt

**input1.txt**: `1 2 3`

**input2.txt**: `a b c`

I am trying to join the lists where each element is paired with another.
So, the output should be:

```
1a
1b
1c 
2a 
2b 
2c 
3a 
3b 
3c
```

With the code I have above, I can only go as far as:

```
1a
1b
1c
```

and it ends.

How can I have it pick the next line and do the same thing over?

Comment: The reason it stops is because files have a pointer to the current location in the file.  When you read from a file, that counter is moved to the current location in the file.  When you read the whole file, the counter is at the end, so it doesn't read anymore.  You could fix your current code by adding `f.seek(0)` before `for line2 in f:`  Use Eithos's answer because it only reads the file once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me like all you really need is this:

```
w = open("input1.txt", "r").read()
f = open("input2.txt", "r").read()

for number in w.split():
    for letter in f.split():
        print number, letter

f.close()
w.close()
```

Just split the results and iterate normally through both. You'll get the number and letter paired together without all that extra (?) code you've already created.

**Edited to reflect new information from OP**

To do what you've asked, use `readlines()` like this:

```
f = open("input2.txt", "r").read().split()
w = open("input1.txt", "r").readlines()

for timestamp in w:
    for letter in f:
        print timestamp.rstrip(), letter
```

The `rstrip` method will take care of `newline` characters that are automatically passed in using `readlines()`.

Comment: I wanted to keep it simple for the example to work but my data looks like this: 
`List 1: 2014 1 1 0 10 0, 

2014 1 1 0 20 0,

 2014 1 1 0 30 0, 2014 1 1 0 40 0, 2014 1 1 0 50 0`
`List 2: a, b, c, d`

List 1 is timestamps.
WIth your code, its picking up one block at a time, 2014, then 1, then 1, then 0

Comment: @armen Can you update that (and format it precisely as it would appear in the file) in your OP?

Comment: @armen In the meantime, can you be more specific about which numbers from list 1 are to be attached to alphabetical counterparts? Do we skip `2014 1 1` and only map the remaining 3 digits to `a, b, c`? You've included a letter `d` here, so this leaves me with some doubts.

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly.
The results should be as follows: `2014 1 1 0 10 0 a, 2014 1 1 0 10 0 b, 2014 1 1 0 10 0 c, 2014 1 1 0 10 0 d`. Then it should pick the next time stamp: `2014 1 1 0 20 0 a, 2014 1 1 0 20 0 b, 2014 1 1 0 20 0 c, 2014 1 1 0 20 0 d`.
Then the next one: `2014 1 1 0 30 0 a, 2014 1 1 0 30 0 b, 2014 1 1 0 30 0 c, 2014 1 1 0 30 0 d`

Comment: @armen Thanks. Is the input actually comma-delimited, or (more likely) is it in separate lines without commas?

Comment: It is in separate lines without commas.

Comment: Ok, so your code works if there are no spaces between the numbers in each timestamp. So instead of 2014 1 1 0 10 0, if it is 2014110100. 

Otherwise it picks up 2014 and processes it: `2014a, 2014b, 2014c, 2014d`. Then picks up 1 and processes it: `1a, 1b, 1c`. So on and so forth

That's why in the original code I had it pick each item from the list and processes it.

Comment: @armen No problem! (If the solution was to your satisfaction, please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. Thank you)

Answer (score 1):

```
s1="1 2 3"
s2 = "a b c"
s1 = s1.split()
s2 = s2.split()
for a in s1:
    for b in s2:
        print(a+b)
1a
1b
1c
2a
2b
2c
3a
3b
3c
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below.

```
w = open('input1', 'r')
f = open('input2', 'r')
for line1 in w:
    words1 = line1.split()
for line2 in f:
    words2 = line2.split()
for z in words1:
    for y in words2:
        print(z+y)
f.close()
w.close()
```

Output:

```
1a
1b
1c
2a
2b
2c
3a
3b
3c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("input1.txt", "r") as f1, open("input2.txt", "r") as f2:
    a = f1.readline().split()
    b = f2.readline().split()

for i in a:
    for x in b:
        print "{}{}".format(i,x)
```

outputs:

```
1a
1b
1c   
2a
2b 
2c
3a
3b
3c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    w = open("input1.txt", "r").read().split()
    f = open("input2.txt", "r").read().split()
    final_list = []
    for number in w:
        final_list += map(lambda:x+number,f)

    f.close()
    w.close()

   print final_list
   >>> [1a,1b,1c,2a,2b,2c,3a,3b,3c]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we simplify the issue by considering that that have 2 lists of strings `a` and `b` now you want to create all the combinations in these lists, then you can simply use :

```
a = ["1", "2", "3"]
b = ["a", "b", "c"]
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        print i+j
```

Now the problem is with reading the list contents from text files.

```
w = open("input1.txt", "r")
f = open("input2.txt", "r")
line1 = w.read()
line2 = f.read()
for word1 in line1.split():
    for word2 in line2.split():
        print word1+word2

f.close()
w.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you read the files fine so lets just assign

```
f=['a','b','c']
w=[1,2,3]
```

then something like this should work:

```
out=[] #blank list
for num in w:
   for let in f:
      out.append(str(num)+let)
```

out is the desired output you posted

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use izip from itertools as follows:-

```
import itertools
w = open("input1.txt", "r")
f = open("input2.txt", "r")

numbers_list = w.readlines()
letters_list = f.readlines()
result = []
for index, numbers in enumerate(numbers_list):
    numbers = numbers.strip('\n').split(' ')
    letters = letters_list[index]
    letters = letters.strip('\n').split(' ')
    for letter in letters:
        paired_tuples= itertools.izip_longest(numbers, '', fillvalue=letter)
        result += [a+b for a,b in paired_tuples]
print result

f.close()
w.close()
```

Handling multiple lines aswell.